# Unity3d Select Object nearest to click no colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, 3d-model

I have a Mixamo Model that I'm using for development.  This model is fully rigged with a skeleton.  I'm trying to create a function that will allow me to select a piece of the skeleton with out having a collider.

This Current Script only works with a collider,

```
public void RegisterSelectControls()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var hit = new RaycastHit();
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
        {
            var objectHitName = hit.collider.transform.name;
            Debug.Log(objectHitName);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to detect which part of the skeleton was click, or the nearest part of the skeleton to the click?

I do not want to add Colliders to every body part manually this would be too excessive and redundant, and if I choose to use a different model I would have to modify the box colliders, I would like to do this with out specifying a box collider

**Edit**

I cannot add colliders to the models, in the future I intend to support allowing a user to upload a model, in which it needs to naturally be able to select parts of the spine to interact with, without the user setting boudaries for the components of the spine

Comment: Different colliders for different body parts. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/64678/head-shot-instant-kill-for-fps-enemies.html

Comment: search google for "unity head shot"

Comment: yeah I know this would work with colliders, however there are too many bones and I don't feel like manually adding colliders for all of them, I would just like to calculate this by registering a click on a 2d plane and  and finding the nearest bone to there

Comment: All the ideas I'm coming up with would perform way worse than colliders. I think it might be easier to write a script that finds bones and assigns colliders and sizes them automatically. I mean, you have to have access to the geometry of the bone in any case, so with that you might be able to auto-add colliders.

Comment: the mixamo bone is lacking the full geometry its only represented by a transform, position and rotation.  I was thinking about writing a script for it, but calculating the length will be fine, but the width collider will really depend on  the model, I wanted to make this more universal, and the are other annoying problems like if bones are nested near each other,  I write it which would be more useful, but I was hoping someone had a hack around this or knew of a function that already does this

Comment: hit.collider.transform.name -> hit.collider.name

Comment: @Fredrik, that would cause me to add the colliders to the model, I intend to allow people to upload there own models in the future, which means I cannot manually add colliders

Comment: Ah, I see your issue. I will think about it. Maybe a collider-generating script? Hehe

Comment: @Fredrik Yeah I was thinking of that, it just might get a little sketchy if bones happen to be nested such as selecting comonents in the head.   I was debating on rendering the image as if it were 2d and mapping where the bones were based on the perspective of the camera, and then tracing there click to a point in the image and then just map it to the closest

Comment: In unity you need to have colliders to test for a click https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/raycast-hit-on-object-without-collider-is-it-possible.44157/#post-280615

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I know what's built into unity, I'm trying to discuss alternative solutions

Comment: Yeah well according to the referenced link you need to manually do all the calculations that a Collier and ray cast does in unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking how to do this it's actually semi simple.  Throw this function in an update loop and have the 'SpineRoot' be equal to the root node of all of the objects you want to check.

```
public void RegisterSelectControls()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var clickLocation = Input.mousePosition;

        Transform closestBone = null;

        this.MinimumRecursiveBoneDistance(clickLocation, SpineRoot, out closestBone);

        if(null != closestBone)
        {
            Debug.Log(closestBone.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}

public float MinimumRecursiveBoneDistance(Vector3 clickLocation, Transform root, out Transform closestBone)
{
    float minimumDistance = float.MaxValue;
    closestBone = null;
    foreach (Transform bone in root)
    {

        var boneScreenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(bone.position);
        var distance = Math.Abs(Vector3.Distance(clickLocation, boneScreenPoint));

        if (distance < minimumDistance)
        {
            minimumDistance = distance;
            closestBone = bone;
        }

        if (bone.childCount > 0)
        {
            Transform closestChildBone;
            var minimumChildDistance = this.MinimumRecursiveBoneDistance(clickLocation, bone, out closestChildBone);
            if(minimumChildDistance < minimumDistance)
            {
                minimumDistance = minimumChildDistance;
                closestBone = closestChildBone;
            }
        }

    }

    return minimumDistance;
}
```

This code can use some refactoring, this was just a proof of concept.  This will work for purely nearest.  However this can yield a potential bug,  If a clicks on an object, and the center of that object is further away from the click that the center of another object you will select the other object.